# SQL Query: How to return products that don't have reviews

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

I have a table of reviews and a table of products. E.g. the following dummy data:

[image]

[image]

I want to return only the products that do not have any reviews.

My SQL code is currently

```
SELECT *
FROM products
LEFT JOIN reviews
ON products.id = reviews.product_id
WHERE reviews.content IS NULL;
```

As each product has multiple reviews, only some of which are null, I'm concerned that this approach returns false negatives (i.e. I don't want products that are associated with some empty reviews among other completed reviews, I only want products for which no reviews exist at all). Do I need to add a HAVING clause?

Thanks much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `join` key for the comparison -- not an arbitrary column:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     reviews r
     ON p.id = r.product_id
WHERE r.product_id IS NULL;
```

Or more colloquially perhaps with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM reviews r
                  WHERE p.id = r.product_id
                 );
```